# Can I skip a global hook in Cucumber if a scenario has a tag?

Tags: ruby, tags, cucumber, hook

In my suite, I have an **After** hook that deletes files from a temp directory when it finishes a scenario. However, there are times in certain scenarios where I do not want to remove files from the temp directory, and I am looking to accomplish this by providing a tag named `@no_cleanup` to the scenario.

Right now, my current **After** hook looks like this:

```rb
After do
  FileUtils.rm_f(Dir.glob(File.join @local_dir, '*'))
end
```

What I want to do is something like, "skip this hook if the scenario has @no_cleanup tagged on it".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated in the [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks) (do not forget to select ruby at the top of the page):

Hooks can be conditionally selected for execution based on the tags of the scenario. To run a particular hook only for certain scenarios, you can associate a `Before`, `After`, `Around` or `AfterStep` Hook with a [tag expression](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions).

```
Before('@browser and not @headless') do
end
```

See more documentation on [tags](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags).

So, in your case, I suppose it should be:

```rb
After('not @no_cleanup') do
  FileUtils.rm_f(Dir.glob(File.join @local_dir, '*'))
end
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed. Thought I'd seen this before, but it slipped my mind. Thanks!